# How do you trigger a custom script in FormB from a form submittal into SheetA though FormA?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you trigger a custom script in FormB from a form submittal into SheetA though FormA?

Or how could I script updating values to a list question in FormB after a response has been submitted in FormA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple ways to achieve that

1. use [apps script libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)  to share the code in both scripts.  might require changes if it uses the "current spreadsheet" or script properties.
2. in script1, publish a webapp with [contentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) publish as anonymous, then from script2 "call" it with urlFetch.
   script1 doGet may receive parameters if you need to make more than one type of call or pass aditional data.

Comment: With regards to option 2 shown below. Would I put my script from the forms needing to be updating in where it says "Hello World"? And then call it from Form 1 using the OnSubmit trigger?

 function doGet() {
   var output = ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello world!");
   return output;
 }